# What does $x$ look like when $x\otimes_k(x^*)^\top$ is Hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a matrix $x\in$[$M_n(\mathbb{C})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_ring) such that $x$[$\otimes_k$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)$(x$[$^*$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose))[$^\top$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)  is [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix), then what does $x$ look like?
Does there exist $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $y\in{M_n(\mathbb{C}})$ such that $x=\alpha{y}$ and $y$ is Hermitian?

Comment: According to your links, you are taking the conjugate-transpose of the transpose. Is $(x^*)^T$ supposed to simply the conjugate of $x$? If so, is there a reason that you're writing $(x^*)^T$ as opposed to simply writing $\bar x$?

Comment: I did that because I was going to ask it only for $x^*$, but then I added the transpose. But, yeah, it is simply the conjugate of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes: $x$ must be a multiple of a Hermitian matrix. This trivially holds for $x = 0$, so I suppose in the below that $x$ is a non-zero matrix (i.e. has at least one non-zero entry).

---

Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the standard basis of $\Bbb C^n$. Note that
$$
(e_j \otimes_k e_k)^* (x \otimes_k \bar x)(e_p \otimes e_q) = x_{jp}\overline{x_{kq}}.
$$
Thus, the condition that $x \otimes_k \bar x$ is Hermitian can be expressed as the statement that for all $1 \leq j,k,p,q \leq n$, the following holds:
$$
x_{jp}\overline{x_{kq}} = \overline{x_{pj} \overline{x_{qk}}} \implies\\
x_{jp} \bar x_{kq} = \bar x_{pj} x_{qk}. \tag{1}
$$

Taking $j = k$ and $p = q$ gives us that for all $1 \leq j,p \leq n$, we have $|x_{jp}|^2 = |x_{pj}|^2$, which implies that $x_{jp}$ is zero iff $x_{pj}$ is zero.

For the cases where both sides of (1) are non-zero, (1) can be written in the neater form
$$
\frac{x_{jp}}{\bar x_{pj}} = \frac{x_{qk}}{\bar x_{kq}}.
$$
To put this another way, this means that there exists some constant $c$ such that for all $1 \leq j,p \leq n$, we have $x_{jp}/\bar x_{pj} = c$. Because we have $|x_{jp}| = |x_{pj}|$ (as stated above), we can further conclude that $|c| = 1$, since for any $p,j$ such that $x_{pj}$ is non-zero (and such indices $j,p$ must exist since $x \neq 0$), we have
$$
|c| = \left|\frac{x_{jp}}{\bar x_{pj}} \right| = \frac{|x_{jp}|}{|\bar x_{pj}|} = 1.
$$

Now, let $d$ denote a solution to $d^2 = c$, and let $y = d x$. Note that $|d| = 1$, so that $\bar d = d^{-1}$. We have
$$
\frac{x_{jp}}{\bar x_{pj}} = c \implies \frac{d y_{jp}}{\bar d \bar y_{pj}} = c \implies \frac{d}{\bar d} \cdot \frac{y_{jp}}{\bar y_{pj}} = c \implies \frac{y_{jp}}{\bar y_{pj}} = 1.
$$

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, though. I'm wondering whether there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $y\in{M_n(\mathbb{C})}$ such that $x=\alpha{y}$ and $y$ is Hermitian. If not, then what does $x_{jp}/\bar{x}_{pj}=x_{qk}/\bar{x}_{kq}$ mean for $x$? Not sure if my question makes total sense or not.

Comment: @mathlover19 See my edit. The answer, if we know that $x$ has no zero-entries, is yes: $x$ must be a multiple of a Hermitian matrix.

Comment: @mathlover19 Actually, this is true in all cases

Comment: What if our diagonal is filled with zeros? Then we can't conclude that $|c|=1$, can we?

Comment: Apparently we can since we can deduce that $\bar{c}=c^{-1}$

Comment: @mathlover19 Instead of using the diagonals, we can use the fact that $|x_{jp}| = |x_{pj}|$ for all $1 \leq p,j \leq n$, which is obtained by plugging in $k= j$ and $q = p$ into equation (1). See my latest edit.